# Modifying a single expression of a dimension in SSAS Cubes

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube

I am working on a SSAS cube and need to make changes to one field in a particular dimension.
The entire table, which I have considered as a dimension, contains a lot of columns. Some of which are Integers, some are nchar and some are dates. The dates are like 2018-01-01, 2017-01-01 and so on. In the cube, I need to filter values by year. Meaning, there should only be 2018, 2017 and so on. In the attached image, I have shown what I am currently seeing. If you look at the circled portion, I need to change that to be just 2018. I also cannot make edits to the source table as it is being used by a lot of different teams.
I tried using the Business Intelligence option, after referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/create-a-custom-member-formula-business-intelligence-wizard?view=sql-server-2014) link,  but it does not show me the values pertaining to dates column. 
Can anyone help me out  ?[image]